# What is the difference between deployed codes and debugging ones in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I made an complicated app that captures screen shot by html2canvas.js on Meteor.
It works well except the below condition.
1. deployed to the server without --debug option. and,
2. client is iOS Safari.

(If you make a simple capturing app by html2canvas.js, it works well for all conditions. So I said "an complicated app", mean that the app includes other libraries.)

What is the essential difference between without --debug option and with --debug option?
(it may be joined or separated, or uglified or not, but they are equivalent.)
Apparently this phenomenon shows they are not equivalent.
Are there any possibilities that the code has interferences by joining files just on iOS?

And how can I debug this problem efficiently?

[UPDATE]
The problem disappeared once I deployed with --debug option and re-deployed without --debug.
It might be related to browser cache policy on iOS.

Comment: Meteor runs minifiers on your code for production use. Minifiers sometimes rename variables and if external libraries rely on some sort of dynamic reflection - they can break. This problem is still open, maybe there should be a way to point at certain libraries and tell Meteor "don't minify these stuff, it just breaks"

Comment: Thank you for your interesting comments. I will care it when reviewing codes.
Still I wonder my problem is different from it. It happens only on iOS though there seems no OS specific codes.

Comment: It is not the first time minifiers don't play nice, there definitely should be a fix to this

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode your code isn't minified and packaged into single files. So there are two modes `debug` and `production`. When you use `meteor deploy` without `--debug` your code is heavily optimized for speed. You would notice this with the time it takes for your app to load on your phone.

If the app works with the `--debug` option only it means you have some kind of javascript error in your app.

When an app is minified all the files are concatenated into a single file. If there is a single error in your code somewhere the rest of the code will not execute. In `--debug` mode the error is still there but because the files are seperated the other files aren't affected by the error.

You should use the javascript console in chrome/safari to look for the error and fix it before you deploy your app. If you're on a mac the easiest way to bring it up is Cmd + Alt + J.

Typically in meteor this is caused by you accessing the collection before its downloaded. Something like trying to get `doc.date` and `doc` is still undefined so it throws a null reference exception.